# removing the word containing hyphen from the start of of each line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to delete the first word(containing hyphen or not) from each line in notepad ++. MY file is like

```
IL-2 gene expression
CD28 surface receptor
activation through
NF-Kappa B
```

and my desired output is like:

```
gene expression
surface receptor
through 
B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the find/replace - using regular expressions this should find the first word (with hyphen) and trailing space.

`^[^\s]+\s`

Then put nothing in the replace field.